# Modify object type at runtime

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible in Objective C to modify an object type at runtime without the compiler complaining?

e.g.

```
id object;
```

in an init method

```
initWithType:(someEnumType) type
```

then depending on type set the object to a class type.

How is this done without the compiler flagging errors that object does not declare someMethod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to do something like that is in a *factory method*, rather than an initializer:

```
typedef enum {
    etString,
    etNumber
} EnumType;

@implementation MyFactory

+(id)makeNewObjectWithType:(EnumType)et {
    id res;
    switch (et) {
        case etString:
            res = [NSString string];
            break;
        case etNumber:
            res = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];
            break;
        default:
            res = nil;
            break;
    }
    return res;
}

@end
```